# Huffman coding for one-symbol sequence but three alphabets

Tags: compression, huffman-code

I'm solving an exercise in a book about compression, it says if we have the alphabet[A,B,C] and probablities P(A)=0.5,P(B)=0.4,P(C)=0.1 how many bits needed for encoding BBB with huffman and arithmetic.

Now the book itself says in a section "BBB requires 6 bits with huffman but only 4 bits with arithmetic", I have verified that arithmetic needs 4 bits but don't know why huffman needs 6.

I solved huffman like this :
B(3)
    P1(3)
EOF(0)  B(3)

so B is encoded with one bit only !!

I thought maybe I should include the whole alphabet like this :
A(0),C(0),B(3)
    P1(0)    B(3)
A(0)    C(0)
          P2(3)
    P1(0)       B(3)
A(0)  C(0)

still B needs 1 bit(but A and C 2 bits, still no 6 !!).

What am I doing wrong here ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out, because P(B)=0.4 so and we have 3 letters we have 3*0.4=1.2 which is approximately 1 and P(A)=0.5 and 3*0.5=1.5 which is between 1 and 2, and P(C)=0.1 and 0.1*3=0.3 which is approximately 0.

So if we sort them we get :
A(1 or 2),B(1),C(0)
and the tree is :
A(1 or 2)     P1(1)
           B(1)   C(0)

P2(2 or 3)
A(1 or 2)       P1(1)
             B(1)    C(0)

In the end one B requires 2 bits so BBB requires 6 bits to encode, problem solved :) .

Answer (score 0):

A has a higher probability than B, so B cannot be assigned fewer bits than A.  The Huffman code gives two bits to B, hence six bits for BBB.

Comment: but the probabilities are for arithmetic coding, huffman is concerned with the count(B occured 3 times), anyway this is better suited as a comment in my opinion

Comment: The probabilities of the symbols are the probabilities of the symbols.  Those probabilities do not depend on how you code the symbols.  They are an input the process.

Comment: Given those probabilities, you in fact get six bits for three B's.  Two bits each.  My answer points out that you calculated the number of bits per symbol in the Huffman code incorrectly.  That should be enough of a clue for you to figure out your error.  I'm not going to hold your hand through your homework.   Your homework is your responsibility.

Comment: sorry I didn't understand at first, I figured it out later, so 3*0.5=1.5 which is between 1 and 2, 3*0.4=1.2 which is approximately 1 so B is 1 and A can be 1 or 2, in either cases BBB requires 6 bits, thank you anyway :)

Comment: can you edit your answer so I can delete my downvote(it's locked :3 ) :)